# Formatting the output of oracle plsql query

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I have a data set like this

```
id        subid        date(in yyyymmdd)  time(in hh24miss)  count1  count2
80013727  20000000431  20120429           001500             0       0
80013727  20000000431  20120429           003000             0       0
80013729  20000000432  20120429           001500             0       0
80013729  20000000432  20120429           003000             0       0
80013728  20000000435  20120429           001500             0       0
80013728  20000000435  20120429           003000             0       0
```

As you can see time is in 15 minutes increment . i want to show output the result set like below.

```
id        Date      subid        00:00:00-00:14:59  00:15:00-00:29:59    
80013727  20120429  20000000431  0                  0
80013729  20120429  20000000432  0                  0
```

as you can see all all the data related to id 80013727 i s shown in one row instead of 2 for the date 20120429.

please tell me how to achieve it.

header row can be printed one time using dbms_output.put_line.

Hi here is your answers-

## oracle ver 10.2 g

for a unique id,subid,date combination count1 and count2 is need to be shown in one row.
instead of 4 rows that can be seen from top most result set.

80013727  20000000431  20120429 has 2 rows for different time (i.e. 015000,030000)

I need to show

80013727  20000000431  20120429 count1(from 1st row),count1(from 2nd row)

80013727  20000000431  20120429 count2(from 1st row),count2(from 2nd row)

Comment: It would be helpful if you could answer a couple questions: 1) what version of Oracle are you using? 2) In the output rows of your desired result set, what computation is used to obtain the values shown in the last two columns? Please edit your question by clicking on the **edit** button beneath the [oracle] and [plsql] tags to answer these questions. Thanks.

Comment: Hi here is your answers-

oracle ver 10.2 g

for a unique id,subid,date combination count1 and count2 is need to be shown in one row.
instead if 4 rows that can be seen from top most result set.

80013727  20000000431  20120429 has 2 rows for different time (i.e. 015000,030000)

I need to show 

80013727  20000000431  20120429 count1(from 1st row),count1(from 2nd row)

Comment: It would make life easier for us if you had written a better question.  Specifically, please include sample data which *explains* how you want the code to work.  Nothing but zeroes is pointless.  Also, you hould fit the desired output to match your rules.  If you take the time to frame your question properly you are more likely to get an answer.  Help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you have simplified your data and your output structure.  I'm guessing you'll end up with 96 count columns (although I'm not going that far either).

```
with cte as
     ( select * from your_table ) 
select id
       ,  subid
       ,  date
           ,  type
           ,  sum(c01) as "00:00:00-00:14:59" 
           ,  sum(c02) as "00:15:00-00:29:59" 
           ,  sum(c96) as "23:45:00-23:59:59" 
from (
    select id
           ,  subid
           ,  date
           ,  'C1' type
           ,  case when time between 0 and 899 then count1 else 0 end as c01 
           ,  case when time between 900 and 1799 then count1 else 0 end as c02
           ,  case when time between 85500 and 86399 then count1 else 0 end as c96
from cte
    union all
    select id
           ,  subid
           ,  date
           ,  'C2' type
           ,  case when time between 0 and 899 then count2 else 0 end as c01 
           ,  case when time between 900 and 1799 then count2 else 0 end as c02
           ,  case when time between 85500 and 86399 then count2 else 0 end as c96
    ) 
group by id, subid, date, type
order by id, subid, date, type
```

So, this use a sub-query factoring expression to select only once from your table.  It uses `case()` to assign counts to a specific time column, on the basis of a range of seconds.  There are two queries to aggregate the counts for lines 1 and 2.

The `sum()` calls may be unnecessary; it's not clear from your data whether you have more than one record in each time slot.